# Issue with variable in REST API powershell

Tags: powershell, rest, api

**Background** : The REST API request works correctly when I remove the variable $Description and put a string in line 11 . If I leave the variable then it doesn't get the value of it , it just uses the name $Description. The variable is working fine since I've tested it by displaying the values through each iteration in the loop.

**Location of issue** : Line 11

**Error Logs** : No errors from powershell

```
$import= Import-Csv -Path C:\Users\ERESULTS.csv -Encoding UTF8  -Delimiter "," -Header "ID", "Description" 
$limit = $import.id.count
$token = "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJyZXBKPqye_X-lBgO3g_XMdlXBdgxsWlXMN2y6sVmF5nlc"
foreach ($line in $import) { 
$ID= $line.ID
$Description= $line.Description 
$params = @{
    Uri         = "https://test.com/rest-api/dataModel/ci/$ID"
    Headers     = @{ 'Authorization' = "Bearer $token" }
    Method      = 'PUT'
    Body        = '{ "dbId" : "$ID", "type" : "business_application", "properties" : {"description" : "$Description" }}'
    ContentType = 'application/json'


}
Invoke-RestMethod  @params
Start-Sleep -Second 2
}
```

Comment: What does `$params.Body` display ahead of invoking the method? I'd consider creating a new object, `$body` separately, perhaps only using double quotes and escaping them where necessary, or using `ConvertTo-Json` on a custom PSObject and then adding it to `$params`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a double-quoted here-string to have variables expand, but without having to escape `"` inside the string:

```bsh
$params = @{
    # ...
    Body        = @"
{ "dbId" : "$ID", "type" : "business_application", "properties" : {"description" : "$Description" }}
"@
    # ...
}
```